# How to deserialize and create objects on heap?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

How to serialize/deserialize object with boost (c++11) when object contains

```
vector<map<u_int64_t, Student*>*>* students;
```

like:

```
class  YearContainer{
public:
vector<map<u_int64_t, Student*>*>* students;

};
```

where class Student has serialize method like

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
     ar & name;
     // ....
}
```

How to deserialize and create all on heap ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it uses the [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/) library.  I don't really see a more specific question here.